# Path of the project I am working on in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I want to know/determine at what path the current project is stored at for an XCode project. (MAC app).
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the project in the Finder. The title bar of the Finder window has an icon, then command-click it. That shows the path to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the command-key and click the project's window title bar area.

PS: This works for most any document or file on OS X.